# Coincident vertices of a face in threejs

Tags: three.js

I am working with threejs implementing some mesh deformations.

I wish to translate a known subset of faces. However, the `Faces3` object only keeps track of its own vertices [a, b, c]. When I translate one of these vertices, it does not translate a non-selected faces's coincident vertex.

So my question is : Given a query face, how can you determine the index of coincident edge vertices.

[IMG](http://postimg.org/image/bypa3dacn/): Translating teal faces. I would like the edge of the yellow and green vertices to move as well.

Comment: well, if the separate objects have been one object and you "cut them up", you could store a reference to the now duplicated vertices. If they are not and you start with separate objects to begin with, you could use a threshold to determine the neighbor-vertices and would have to iterate over all the vertices of all adjacent objects.

Comment: Try calling `geometry.mergeVertices()` and see how you like the effect.